# How can I add ítems to cart in Magento 1.9 but in specific store?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

hello I have 4 stores configured in magento 1.9, but I need to add items to the cart in a specific store with ID 8, I have tried the following code but it does not work.

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->setStoreId(7);
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($productId, array('qty' => $qty));
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

I hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: Please be more elaborate with your question and show what you have tried also the error or an issue

Comment: yes, sorry I figure out. I fixed it.

Comment: `setStoreId($storeId)` to `$cart` has no effect as it is not used. Instead, try `if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() == $storeId} { $cart->init()->addProduct($productId, $qty); ...}`